# How to use a global variable across multiple files while importing a function from another fil

Tags: python, function, import, global-variables

I have been trying to work with importing from different files and it keeps giving me circular import errors. Could anyone help with this:

**file --> main.py**

```
from first import main
number1 = None
main()
```

**file --> first.py**

```
from base import number1

def main():
    global number1
    number1 = input("Type the first number: ")
    try:
        number1 = float(number1)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input! Please Try Again!")
        print("")
        main()
```

Comment: what is 'base' in `from base import number1` ?

Comment: Ah sorry, the file was called base.py not main.py.
I accidentally wrote main.py in this question.
But the code still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

here is what's happening:

1. `first.py` tries to import `number1` from `base.py`.
2. `base.py`, in turn, tries to import `main` from `first.py`, so it opens `first.py`, and what's the first line of code there?! that's right, `from base import number1` which creates an import loop.

One solution is to create a third module for global variables and import it wherever needed:

globalvar.py:

```
number1 = None
```

base.py:

```
from first import main
import globalvar
main()
print(globalvar.number1)
```

first.py:

```
import globalvar

def main():
    number2 = input("Type the first number: ")
    try:
        globalvar.number1 = float(number2)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input! Please Try Again!")
        print("")
        main()
```

[further reading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/).